# When is it the right time to start teaching collision detection?

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection

I and a friend of mine started a game development club in our school two months ago and everything is going well for now. We are following [McKesson's tutorials](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) which I find comprehensive and well-built.

We have come to the point where we started making simple prototypes of easy-to-do games, like [3D Pong](http://www.freegames.ws/games/free_online_games/pong_game/3d_pong.htm) (not as polished as the referenced version), and soon we are going to finish the second part of the tutorials (the Positioning of objects). We have ideas for prototypes which involve little more complex collision detection and I started wondering is it a good place to look in depth at this topic of game programming? And should I also include the BSP, quadtrees, octrees and other partitioning algorithms with it?

Comment: The collision detection part is independent of what that online book teaches people, that being rendering. Once you know how to display wireframe or simple polytopes, you can consider playing with collision detection.. which itself is the broadest field of Game Physics (since it comprises the usage of the data structures you mentioned).

Comment: I understand that the book is for rendering, but our club is about game development and we should cover physics too. I just wanted to know if this is the right time to start exploring collision detection (also game physics but this is off-topic).

Comment: The "right time" is when you want to make a game that needs that feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in the comments.

The "right time" is when you want to make a game that needs that feature.